# Jquery Ajax Html Response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

Hi We have Rails application,

We implemented the JQuery Ajax. The Url was got excuted and got result in data object as html.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: u,
    data: {
        id: id,
        LANG: "ENG"
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, err, e) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    }
});
```

our Html response is  :

```
<html>
  <span id='rate'>  
    <img src="www.text.comt/star.gif" width=10, height=10 >
  </span>
</html>
```

Actually there are 5 image tag will come the span section. We want get all the 5 image tag and display the impages in our application.

How can we do this with "data" object.

Comment: you have to use $.each, so you can get one by one image.

Comment: Make your application just return a scrap of HTML (drop the html) so you can embed it directly. Alternatively (and cleaner), you can have it return JSON or something like that so your can just iterate through it and handle the markup on the client side

Comment: can u post what u r getting in data object

Answer (score 1):

If you are **really** sending back `HTML` data from your server this way is possible:

```
success: function (data, textStatus){  
  // jQuery('<selector_where_you_want_to_append').append($(data).find('img')); 
  jQuery('body').append($(data).find('img')); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$.load` function in jquery if you're just loading html. I'm not really familiar on how things are done on ruby but you can also return a json string from the server and iterate over it to generate html using JavaScript. Here's how you can use `$.load`

```
$('.container').load(url, {id: id,LANG: "ENG"});
```